# Render result for a Form rails / gem geocoder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to render the result of my form when users are clicking on the "Search" button.

I think I am missing something with the Model (i dont really know if i have to add something on my user model) or the Html.

**I have a controller : Searchscontroller**

```
class SearchsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:city].present?
      @searchs = User.near(params[:city], params[:distance] || 10, order: :distance)
    else
      @searchs = User.all
    end
  end
```

**and a form in search.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag search_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= label :user, "Search User near : " %>
  <%= text_field_tag :city, params[:city] %>

  <%= label :distance, "Distance : " %>
  <%= text_field_tag :distance, params[:distance] %>

  <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>

  #NOT SURE WITH THAT PART, I think its not working, just the %else is displayed#
    <div>
    <% if @searchs.present? %>
      <%= render @searchs %> # it might be @users instead ? #
    <% else %>
      <p>Oops no user around <%= params[:city] %>.</p>
    <% end %>
    </div>
```

My users have been located with the gem geocoder, that part is fine, I got Lat and Longitude (and the city in DB, its working in the console User.Near('City') ), but I just would like to display a list of result , like this when I click on the form :

> > Around London / distance 10 km  => >Search<
> >         
> > Result  
> > > @user 1  
> > > @user 2

I hope someone got the answer for me, many thanks in advance

Route.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 devise_for :users
 resources :users, only: [:index, :show]
 root "pages#home"
 get "search" => "pages#search"
```

Comment: Can you post your `routes.rb` file and also renaming your `def index` action to `def search` and seeing if that helps?

Comment: I will update the question with my route.rb , I will try to rename right now, thanks for your answer !

Comment: It looks like you may need to also add a route for your `searchs#search` action. Try adding something like `get '/city_search', to: 'searchs#search`. If you want to take this to chat so I can explain in further detail how this all works I would be happy to do that.

Comment: Thanks Anthony, I will try to add a route for the searchs#search , I thought my code in the html was wrong <% if @searchs.present? %> and the render. If i can't find any solution, i will ask you directly , thanks again !!

Comment: I looked at that too, and while not the most elegant solution, it seems like it should work. You could just change that to `<% if @searchs? %>` if you wanted. Good luck and please reach out if you have questions! I'm happy to help/mentor.

Comment: I found a solution , I changed the route.rb like you said. I change the path of my html form ('searchs / search.html.erb'). And i changed the render , it was a partial so , I replaced it with a ~"  <% @searchs.each do |search| %> "~ the problem now is that the table is always displayed , but it worked and when I change the parameters ,the table is changing with the right values. I need to check how to render the table only when i press the Search Button . Thanks again Anthony

Comment: @MartinRails If you've solved this, could you add your answer, so it helps others that might be in a similar condition?

Comment: Yes of course , I Will try to explain it clearly ;)

Answer (score 0):

So basically, I changed the folder of my search file > 
"searchs/search.html.erb"
And the route in Route.rb :  `get "search" => "searchs#search"`

```
     <%= form_tag search_path, method: :get do %>
      <%= label :user, "Search User near : " %>
      <%= text_field_tag :city, params[:city] %>

      <%= label :distance, "Distance : " %>
      <%= text_field_tag :distance, params[:distance] %>

      <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
    <% end %>
```

The class is still the same, just renamed the def "*index*" to "*search*" :

```
    class SearchsController < ApplicationController
        def search
        if params[:city].present?
          @searchs = User.near(params[:city], params[:distance] || 10)
        else
          @searchs = User.all
        end
      end
    end
```

and the main problem was the div at the end of the form to display the results (the precedent code was looking for a partial *_search.html.erb* and I didn't created it, so I wrote this , to display the result of the form directly.

```
    <div>
     <table>
      <tr>
      <th>Nickname</th>
      <th>City</th>
      </tr>
        <% @searchs.each do |search| %>
            <tr>
            <td><%= search.nickname %></td>
            <td><%= search.city %></td>
            </tr>
    <% end %>
      </table>
    </div>
```

I still dont know how to display the result only when I'm clicking on the "*Search*" button (it's just refreshing the form right now), but I got an idea with a Partial _form for the results. If someone got a solution for this , add it in the comment ;)